# Steps to solve $\int \sqrt{\frac{11}{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

What are the steps required to solve the following?

$\int \sqrt{\frac{11}{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

I'm not looking for anyone to do my homework.  I usually have no problem figuring these things out -- using Wolfram Alpha step-by-step if absolutely necessary -- but for some reason this seemingly simple problem has me stumped.

Below are the Wolfram Alpha step-by-step instructions for doing this.  I get lost on the part where they do the u substitutions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Remove a constant, and then write a power of $x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need for a substitution, and that only complicates matters and obscures what's important. Write

$$\sqrt{\frac{11}{x}} = \frac{\sqrt{11}}{\sqrt x} = \sqrt{11} x^{-1/2}$$

Now integrate:

\begin{align*}
\int \sqrt{11} x^{-1/2} dx &= \sqrt{11} \int x^{-1/2} dx \\
&= \sqrt{11} \frac{x^{-1/2 + 1}}{-1/2 + 1} + C \\
&= \sqrt{11} \frac{x^{1/2}}{1/2} + C \\
&= 2 \sqrt{11} x^{1/2} + C \\
&= 2 \sqrt{11 x} + C
\end{align*}

Comment: Ah yes.  I couldn't see the forest for the trees.  Thank you very much.

Comment: You're very welcome. You should always look to pull constants out, and deal with single powers of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = x^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't believe that I didn't figure that out on my own.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Remove the constant.  Then note that $\sqrt\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$.

You should be able to go from here simply applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  The derivative of *what* will give you $x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$?

Comment: Yes, it was simple as I guessed that it was.  I think I was thrown by Wolfram Aplha's convoluted solution (and result).  Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem @GaryWhite.  Unfortunately, WolframAlpha isn't human, so the output will often be a bit clunky/unintuitive.  I'm glad I could help!